# How to include NOT in Rails query before Rails 4 when it is tied with other parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to combine an existing Rails query with a NOT query. I read that Rails 4 supports this well, but I'd like to know how to do it in Rails 3.

```
@next_question = Answer.where(:topic => subject, :result => session.question_pool, :user_id => current_user.id, 'practicesession_id != ?', params[:session_id]).first
```

I've tried the above and keep getting an error. The portion that relates to the NOT is the last bit of the query (practicesession_id). Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In rails 3 this will work

```
@next_question = Answer.where(:topic => subject, :result => session.question_pool, :user_id => current_user.id)
                 .where(Answer.arel_table[:practicesession_id].not_eq(params[:session_id])).first
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@next_question = Answer.where(topic: subject, result: session.question_pool, user_id: current_user)
                       .where('practicesession_id != ?', params[:session_id]).first
```

You can chain your wheres together, using AR syntax in some, and SQL strings in others.